# setting max_input_vars PHP.ini directive using ini_set

Tags: php, php-ini

Can I set the max_input_vars PHP.ini directive in my code? I have it set at the default 1000, however I have a script that has many checkboxes and text fields that could, and quite possibly will, go over the 1000 limit.

I'm using PHP 5.3.10 and i'm not getting any errors doing this. Also, I can't find any documentation that states I can't do this.

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 3000);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP max\_input\_vars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303714/php-max-input-vars)

Comment: It it doesn't work then you can put following in your .htaccess file:

php_value max_input_vars 5000

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[`max_input_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) has a changeable mode of [`PHP_INI_PERDIR`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) meaning it can't be changed using `ini_set` (only in php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf)

Comment: And the main reason is that the directive has already taken effect when the PHP code starts running.

Comment: For future readers add to your .htaccess: php_value  max_input_vars  3000

Comment: @MichaelCalkins is it possible to make `php_value max_input_vars 3000` in .htaccess  to work only for one php file and not for all?

Comment: @Michael: If you read the above, you will see that using ini_set won't work

Comment: It works in .htaccess like this:

php_value max_input_vars 10000

Answer (score 11):

I know many people avoid accessing `php.ini` due to one reason or the other. so another way would be to create a [`.htaccess`](https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/htaccess#Creating%20A%20.htaccess%20File) file in the operation folder and add the following codes and set the values to a higher value. Just add them directly no need to initialize anything in the `.htaccess` file

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 3000
```

This solution worked for me without accessing the `php.ini` file. since some of the web host providers give us a hard time when we want to access the `php.ini` file

Comment: I like this solution better than the accepted answer, because you can localize the change to a specific domain / subdomain (if you have multiple on your server) and a specific directory within that domain (for example, /api or /ajax, or some other).