# Truncated/missing form data when form contains large number of inputs?

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, nginx

**The Background**
I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.4 and PHP 5.3 running on Nginx. I have an HTML form representing what is essentially rows of homogeneous data. Each "row" has several `<input />` fields, each with the same name. Here's a simplified example:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname[]" />
<input type="text" name="lastname[]" />
```

So, I've got many `firstname[]` inputs, `lastname[]` inputs, etc. After submitting the form (the action is `POST`), I retrieve the data in a controller method like so (note that I'm using CodeIgniter):

```
$firstnames = $this->input->post('firstnames');
$lastnames = $this->input->post('lastnames');
```

These variables are arrays containing the values from the corresponding rows in the form, and from here I do some processing on this data.

**The Problem**
When the number of rows in the form is large (several hundred), the size of the resulting PHP arrays **do not match the number of inputs in the form** -- for example, the form might have 200 `firstname` inputs, but the `$firstname` array only has 167. What's more, the `$lastname` variable has a different size as well -- 166.

When the form has a smaller number of elements, everything works fine.

My theory is that I am exceeding some sort of maximum size setting or buffer somewhere in the stack, causing the form data to be truncated. Is there a PHP or CodeIgniter or nginx setting for "maximum form size" that I am not aware of?

For what it's worth, I have seen the same behavior when using both `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the content type for the form.

What am I missing?

Comment: Most likely you have the suhosin php security patch installed. It limits the number of input parameters allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming no suhosin... Then see: [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) and [max_input_nesting_level](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-nesting-level).

These are newer and often overlooked when people think of POST limits in PHP.

But if its truncated like you say then maybe it is just your [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size).

Also, this just has to be a dupe question...

[PHP max_input_vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303714/php-max-input-vars)
[Increasing the maximum post size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size)
etc..

Comment: The problem was `max_input_vars`. It was set at 1000, and each "row" in my form had 6 inputs. 1000 / 6 = 166.6; so whenever I had more than 167 "rows", I encountered  this problem (and some of my arrays contained 166 items, while others contained 167). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Mine was commented. I just un-comment it and set to 10000. So far so good. If this is a mistake, somebody please comment.