# Configuring php.ini in Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am trying to change the variable *max_input_vars* in my php.ini file by specifying

```
; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
max_input_vars = 2500
```

and running

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Even though I set this variable to 2500 on both my local machine (C:\xampp\php\php.ini) and on Homestead (/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini),
I keep receiving the following error message

```
  parse_str(): Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini
```

I know .htaccess overrides php.ini on a per site basis, are there any other files which override php.ini?  Are there any other services that need to be reloaded after changing the php.ini file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 2500);
```

At the beginning of this file `bootstrap/autoload.php`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  Yes, I tried calling that method, but it didn't seem to make a difference.  Can you think of anything else that might work instead?

Comment: Sure, remember change "max_input_vars" and "post_max_size" too. Try it.

Comment: No luck.  Would I need to change the HandleExceptions class so that it doesn't throw an error if there are more than 1000 input vars?

Comment: Do you have any xdebug error? If this is your case then place this code ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 120); in the top of bootstrap/autoload.php

Comment: Well it turns out that adding my application to the hosts file and the .env file fixed the problem.  For some reason the max_input_vars is only an issue when running off `php artisan serve`.  I am going to accept this as the correct answer, but if you have any insight into where the configuration file is for `php artisan serve`, I would be interested in hearing it.

Comment: I also learned that the command `php --ini` displays the loaded configuration files and values

Comment: The second argument must be a string: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php. .htaccess seems to be required: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14166562/5296404

Answer (score 5):

On the latest laravel homestead, php.ini is located in

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
```

(Make sure you enter into ssh in to the homestead environment)

try to edit it using

```
sudo su
```

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem in laravel

i added

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 2500);
```

in server.php when use laravel

Answer (score 0):

SSH to the virtual machine:

```
homestead ssh
```

The latest version of PHP in Homestead is 7.1. Edit the corresponding php.ini file:

```
sudo vim /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
```

Search for `max_input_vars` and change its value.