# i can't save micromanage tariffs of a business on jomres in joomla

Tags: joomla, jomres

I make a new micromanage tariff for a business in jomres and I try to save it, but then a message shows that I should make a tariff. When I create my tariff it doesn't save.

I tried to find a solution  on the internet but  didn't find anything that helps. What am I doing wrong? How can I save my tariff?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your max_input_vars setting. On a default installation this may be as low as 600 or less, whereas ideally you should try to set them to about 2000.

[PHP max_input_vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303714/php-max-input-vars)