# Codeigniter - 403 Forbidden Access when sending array with 3000 entries via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a Controller which consumes Ajax requests and responds with the result of the database operation. The Ajax call is formed with a set of IDs (an array of ints) and a message.

When the set of IDs have a normal ammount of IDs (I tested with 20 IDs), the Ajax call returns normally. When trying to send 3000 IDs, I get an almost instant response with a 403 Forbidden Access error.

This is probably a Codeigniter or Apache server error. I looked for it, but didn't find any answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the max post size ?

Comment: @ElaBuwa I didn't, how can I check it? Also, how can I check the total size of the POST request? The Network tab on Firefox only show the header size and content length, not content size.

Comment: Checked maximum POST size: 8MB.

Comment: content length is content size in bytes

Comment: The content-length wasn't higher than 8MB (8*2^20).

Answer (score 0):

On your AJAX code, are you sending it via GET?, if so, change it to POST

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'url',
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //some code
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm sending via POST. When I had few IDs selected, the AJAX call is returned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

By default php.ini has 1000 max_input_vars variable.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303714/php-max-input-vars) you have the docs how to change

Change that and you will fix the issue. I had the same problem before.

Ex: placing following lines into .htaccess

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 3000
```