# Setting PHP Max Input Vars

Tags: php, .htaccess, ini

I need to adjust the default server value for Max Input Vars on a website>

Writing `ini_set('max_input_vars', 3000)` on a script does not work

Adding the following to .htaccess makes the whole site go blank

```
php_value max_input_vars 1000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 1000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 1000
```

We dont have access to the ini file.

Is there a way round this at the script level?

Comment: The `max_input_vars` setting is [`PHP_INI_PERDIR`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php), which means it cannot be set via `ini_set`. The site going blank with the `.htaccess` means a useful error message is sitting in the logs - find it and fix.

Comment: why having so many vars? just group them … in a data structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP max\_input\_vars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303714/php-max-input-vars)

Comment: The wordpress theme requires that setting for it to work.