# How to apply max_input_vars value to specific controller in cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

PHP, by default, does not post more than 1000 form fields.
I can increase limit by using "php_value max_input_vars 5000" in htaccess. But I want to apply to specific url using .htaccess.

```
ini_set('max_input_vars',2000); //cannot set runtime.
```

for example : I want to apply only when controller is Teachers and method is details.

For other controllers, it should be default.
**myurl**   http://localhost/proejct/admin/teachers/details.

Comment: check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303714/php-max-input-vars

Comment: How can one check your localhost URL?

Comment: http://localhost/proejct/admin/teachers/details. this url for understanding no need to change.

Comment: Hi Bhupesh, I want to set specific url max_input_vars using .htaccess file.