# How can I Send VERY LONG forms to users

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

So basically I have a wordpress site and my aim is to let users pay for a service and after the payment they have to fill a form.Everything works fine except the fact that the form is TOO HUGE (nearly 400~500 fields) and has many field conditions too. I tried using ARForms, works fine but because of the size the form stops responding in between.

Is there any way in which i can achieve this ? Any offline methods also where i can send forms to the users and they fill and send it back to me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why in the world would anyone pay you so they can fill out a 400-500 field form? I hope you are at least warning people about that before they pay you. I'm not sure what your form is for, but it seems excessive. That said, you probably need some sort of form wizard. Basically, don't show the whole form at once, just a part of it. Once that part is complete, show the next part, etc. This is a good idea anyways for such a large form because you can save portions of it in the database between different parts of the form so no data is lost on an accidental page refresh or something.

Comment: Split the form in smaller parts. 80-100 fields each form, submit it, send user to next form. You can name your submit buttons something like "Next Page" so user is not confused, up till the last button that should say "Complete" or something related.

Comment: Or, if you really want to do this, look at [increasing your max_input_vars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10303714/231316) possibly.