# My mysql.sql file is corrupted and I cannot import it into Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

I'm using Xampp Server 127.0.0.1 version:10.1.9-MariaDB PHP/5.6.15 phpMyAdmin 4.5.1 Apache 2.4.17 and the database worked good in my website then I made a back up copy and reinstald Xampp and now I try to import my database I get these error and I can not import the database and if I can not import it into Xampp thin I can not fix if!
8 errors were found during analysis.

```
Variable name was expected. (near " " at position 22)
Variable name was expected. (near " " at position 32)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "br" at position 1)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "b" at position 8)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "Warning" at position 10)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "b" at position 19)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near ":" at position 21)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "Unknown" at position 24)
```

SQL query: Copy

> Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the
> limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in **Unknown** on line
> **0**
>  -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump -- version 4.5.1 --
> http://www.phpmyadmin.net -- -- Host: 127.0.0.1 -- Generation Time:
> Aug 17, 2020 at 07:33 PM -- Server version: 10.1.9-MariaDB -- PHP
> Version: 5.6.15 SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '
>  **Warning**:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000.
> To increase t...' at line 1

Comment: This is hard to read. Could you please format the question? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help if unfamiliar. Also this sounds like just a mysql task, are you trying to restore from PHP?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303714/php-max-input-vars) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP max\_input\_vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303714/php-max-input-vars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error message you get on import, it appears that is failing because there was an error when you originally exported the DB.

This line was prepended to your SQL export:

> "Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the
> limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0"

That explains why the import is failing, the export file is not in the correct format.

You can confirm this by noticing the warning:

> Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "Warning" at position 10)

Which is not valid SQL.

You can try the following and see if it works:

Open your SQL export and delete everything that appears before this line:

> -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump -- ...

Hopefully the rest of the file, without that error message, is well constructed and you will have the ability to import.

Comment: will I can not export the file because it not in Xampp to export and I have increase the max_input_vars to 9000

Comment: ho that database was working good at the time I exported it

Comment: will it took me a long time to figure out what you were saying I did not know you can right click on a SQL file and open it. the last back up file had that warning in it and that was all no tables and no data so I look at the next one back and the same was there so I look at the next one after that and it had the warning and tables and data so I did what you said and it worked so I think you a lot