# POST request cutted array data

Tags: php, laravel

I have two apps build on Laravel 8.
They communicate each other by standard Guzzle Client.
One of that app sent by POST request, array with 98 elements. Every element is a array with 12 short text items as associated array.

When second app receive request then there is only 91 elements and the last one contain only 1 value.

Why this request is cutted?

Data structure:

```
[
  'users' => [
      [], [], [], .....
  ]
]
```

When I sent the same array but before I encoded it by json_encode. Then second app receive full content.
So why array is cutted?

My "post_max_size" is set to 8MB.

Regards

Comment: Maybe there is a default `max_input_vars` setting in php.ini? Usually a 1000. You need to increase it. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303714/php-max-input-vars

Comment: @Robert You where right. Thank you. But why? Check my data structure I added now. I hade only one field "users" with data. So wheat really means that 1000? And anyway I had only 98 elements in array.

Comment: Didn't you say every element contains up to 12 attributes? So do the math 91 x 12 comes to over 1,000

Comment: @BernardWiesner ahh ok so this is how system calculated. I though for system is 98. Thank you.