# Html form has more than 1000 fields. so form is break after 1000 fields.How to increase the php gobal variable max_input_vars

Tags: php, forms, post

Html  form has more than 1000 fields. so form is break after 1000 fields.How to increase the php gobal  variable max_input_vars.

ini_set('max_input_vars',3000);// is not working
echo phpinfo();//show only 1000

Comment: Having more than 1000 fields in a form sounds like a UX-nightmare

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973555/setting-max-input-vars-php-ini-directive-using-ini-set)

Comment: try to use php.ini

Comment: yes @VasiliyLetuyev have to php.ini file